# Oozie shell action to create python virtual env

Tags: python, oozie, oozie-workflow

Hi all We are trying to create a python virtual environment through oozie shell action. But oozie is not recognizing virtualenv command inside the shell script.

After the virtual environment is created we are trying to download a file using python rest API. But we are unable to cross the creation of virtual environment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: an Oozie shell action executes on an arbitrary data node. You probably don't have virtualenv installed on every data node. Nobody can give a concrete answer without seeing any Oozie workflows or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oozie shell action executes on a Node Manager, that node may not have virtual environment installed hence the failure.